# svn ant build and patches

Tags: svn

I perform ant builds with a SVN source code control systems. Every build process creates a War file- which is a package of individual jar files.

My development team  wants to create a patch for the resources properties file (not included in the build- but included in the source code control SVN).

Any thoughts of how I can incorporate this patch and create a new build - without having to rerun my  build process?

Answer (score 0):

It depends where your property file must be located within the war, but you can considered one of the [nested elements of the `war ant` task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/war.html) and try using one of those (based on a [`FileSet`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/fileset.html)).
For instance `webinf`.

> The nested `webinf` element specifies a `FileSet`.
>   All files included in this `fileset` will end up in the `WEB-INF` directory of the `war` file.
>   If this `fileset` includes a file named `web.xml`, the file is ignored and you will get a warning.